# How to send data by clicking UITableViewCell's button to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, navigation

I want to send data using a button click which is in uitableviewcell. I got the data from web service. Each row button send different data to viewController.
 Attach cellForRowAtIndex Method below:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *identifier = @"CategoryCell";
NSDictionary *dictMenuData = [_arrHandMadeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if(!cell) {
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CategoryCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
    cell = (CategoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
}

cell.btnShowRatingDetails.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.btnShowRatingDetails addTarget:self action:@selector(showRatingClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[arrReview removeAllObjects];
//arrReview = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"RivewData"];
[arrReview addObjectsFromArray:[dictMenuData objectForKey:@"RivewData"]];

[cell setupHandMadeCell:dictMenuData];

return cell;
}
```

Method for button is below:

```
-(void) showRatingClicked:(UIButton*)sender {

//if (sender.tag == currentIndex) {
ReviewVC *rvc = (ReviewVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReviewVC"];

rvc.arrReviewDetails = arrReview;
rvc.strRestaurentName = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"Restaurant_Name"];
rvc.strRestaurentId = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"Restaurant_Id"];
rvc.strRestaurentRating = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"Stars"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
//}
}
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: it only send last index of tableview

Comment: Its because you are refilling the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `NSDictionary *dictReview = [_arrHandMadeList objectAtIndex:sender.tag];` in `-(void) showRatingClicked:(UIButton*)sender` to get the appropriate dictionary, then use it at the place of `dictMenuData`.

Remove `dictMenuData` altogether from your code.

Comment: Glad that it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the index of selected cell button. You can get it from sender.tag.

```
-(void) showRatingClicked:(UIButton*)sender {

ReviewVC *rvc = (ReviewVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReviewVC"];

NSDictionary *dictMenuData = [_arrHandMadeList objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

rvc.arrReviewDetails = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"RivewData"]; //or as per your data
rvc.strRestaurentName = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"Restaurant_Name"];
rvc.strRestaurentId = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"Restaurant_Id"];
rvc.strRestaurentRating = [dictMenuData objectForKey:@"Stars"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];

}
```

Once `cell.btnShowRatingDetails.tag = indexPath.row;` button is assigned the tag you can get the data object in the action method, same way you get it using `indexpath.row`.